# Struts Validation Framework not working

Tags: java, validation, struts, struts-1

I am trying to validate a form using struts validation framework, but the validation seems to be getting bypassed. I have all the validations setup in validation.xml.

I also have some custom form validations in the form's `validate()` method which are running fine.

I have set the `validate="false"` in the action mapping and calling the form's validate explicitly from the action's `doPerform()`

I am on Struts 1.

Here's some code:

> Inside the action

```
if(validationPassed(changeForm, mapping, request)){
 if( !(changeForm.getResultAction().equals("add")) )
   if(!businessValidationsPassed(changeForm, request))
     errorFlag = true;
   }
   else{
        errorFlag = true;
   }

private boolean validationPassed(MultiChangeForm form, ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request ) {

  ActionErrors errors =  form.validate(mapping, request);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        saveErrors(request, errors);
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;

}
```

> struts-config.xml

```
<action path="/multiController"
            type="com.multi.action.MultiControllerAction"
            name="MultiChangeForm"  
            scope="session"
            input="multiUpdateResult.def"
            validate="false">
   <forward name="success" path="/forward/initProcess/cam/multiUpdateResultDef.do"/> 
        <forward name="failure" path="/forward/initProcess/cam/multiUpdateResultDef.do"/>
        <forward name="error" path="/forward/initProcess/cam/errorDef.do"/>

</action>

<plug-in className="org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn">
    <set-property property="pathnames"
                  value="/WEB-INF/multi/validator-rules.xml,/WEB-INF/multi/validation.xml"/>
</plug-in>
```

> form's validate()

```
ActionErrors errors =  super.validate(actionMapping, request);
// custom validations: running ok
```

Am I missing something over here? Any ideas would be really great.

Thanks

Sahil

Comment: You say the validations are running fine--what, then, is actually happening?

Comment: Actually the validations which were put inside the validate() were running fine. But those inside validation.xml were not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When validation of the form fails, you are sent to the `input` page specified in the `<action>` tag, so I don't know why you are calling the validate method manually.

Anyways.... what I suspect is that your `MultiChangeForm` form is extending [`ActionForm`](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/apidocs/org/apache/struts/action/ActionForm.html) when in fact it should extend [`ValidatorForm`](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/apidocs/org/apache/struts/validator/ValidatorForm.html).

Are you extending `ValidatorForm`?

Comment: Hi.. yes the form is extending ValidatorForm.

Comment: @Sahil Dave: The `ValidatorForm` has something like this in its validate method : `try { validatorResults = validator.validate(); } catch (ValidatorException e) { log.error(e.getMessage(), e); }`. I'm thinking that maybe you get an exception which is swallowed?! Try activating the logs and see if something pops up. Additionally you could try reviewing your code against [the validator guide](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.4/userGuide/dev_validator.html) and see if something is different in your setup.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you mixed validate method and validator framework.

For validate method we don't need any validation rules(no need xmls). Simply we can write validate method in `formBean` class and we can add errors to `ActionErrors` object.

Validator framework(xmls) is used to validate on client side.
In jsp we provide rules like `mask` or `intRange`, `FloatRange` , email validation..

Comment: Hi.. yes I know validation.xml is used to apply rules for client side validation. But it can also be called manually by calling super.validate(mapping, request) in the form's validate() method.

Answer (score 0):

Found out why validation.xml was getting bypassed.
I had put in some comments inside the file.
    
Looking closely at the server console while deploying the app, I found that the server was not able to parse the xml due the above tag.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for facing this issue is, validator-rules.xml version doesn't match with the current struts version. when we do upgrade the current struts version , we might have left the validator-rules.xml unmodified. The below link explains the same.

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.struts.user/137543

In my case, I am using struts 1.1. But I have downloaded the validator-rules.xml from some external site and used which is not compatible with my struts version.

Hence, as a step of solution First, Find the struts.jar used in your application and open the manifest file and find out the Struts version used. Because even in version 1.2 we may have so many variants, we wanna find the exact validator-rules.xml. Secondly, get the relevant validator-rules.xml from downloading the struts in the below mentioned link and use the validator-rules.xml in your application

http://archive.apache.org/dist/struts/